# Incorrect login details were provided

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi I work on discord bot and I have a problem I created an environment variable but discord can't log me. Can you help I didn't find the solution on stack thanks for your reading.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const process = require('process');
const token_discord = process.env.token_discord 

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  };
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rip'){

        const attachement = new Discord.Attachment('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png');
        message.channel.send(attachement);
    }
});

client.login('token_discord');
```

```sh
(node:21865) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
    at WebSocketConnection.client.ws.connection.once.event (/Users/lucas/Desktop/discord-shiba/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientManager.js:48:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at WebSocketConnection.onClose (/Users/lucas/Desktop/discord-shiba/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
    at WebSocket.onClose (/Users/lucas/Desktop/discord-shiba/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (/Users/lucas/Desktop/discord-shiba/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:191:10)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnClose (/Users/lucas/Desktop/discord-shiba/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:850:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
(node:21865) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:21865) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Last line, your passing it a string of 'token_discord', not the variable. Remove the quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple things here. 
A discord token is the Bot Token that allows your bot to login. You can get that from your developers console.
The token is stored in the local environment to keep it safe. This line fetches it `const token_discord = process.env.token_discord`
Then you use that token to login
`client.login('token_discord');` this however is trying to login with the STRING 'token_discord' not the variable token_discord. Try removing the single quotes around that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your bot's discord token where it says `token_discord` on the last line.

If you don't know where to get a discord bot token, go to https://discordapp.com/developers and create an application.